# How the custom object is stored in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

I have a problem in understanding below code how `heavenlyBody.addSatellite(satellites );` is added into HashMap ?

when `HeavenlyBody planet1 = solarSystem.get("Mars");` is called the planet1.getSatellites() returns Phobos and Deimos satellites for planet Mars and satellite Moon for plant Earth.

My question is how Phobos and Deimos are added to Mars key in solarSystem HashMap ?

```
   public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, HeavenlyBody> solarSystem = new HashMap<>();

        // Create Planet
        HeavenlyBody heavenlyBody = new HeavenlyBody("Mars", 10.2);
        solarSystem.put(heavenlyBody.getName(), heavenlyBody);

        // Create Satellite
        HeavenlyBody satellites  = new HeavenlyBody("Phobos", 01.2);
        solarSystem.put(satellites .getName(), satellites );
        heavenlyBody.addSatellite(satellites );

        // Create Satellite
        satellites  = new HeavenlyBody("Deimos", 01.2);
        solarSystem.put(satellites .getName(), satellites );
        heavenlyBody.addSatellite(satellites );

        heavenlyBody = new HeavenlyBody("Earth", 365);
        solarSystem.put(heavenlyBody.getName(), heavenlyBody);

        satellites  = new HeavenlyBody("Moon", 27);
        solarSystem.put(satellites .getName(), satellites );
        heavenlyBody.addSatellite(satellites );

        // Get the List of Satellites for Planet Mars and Earth
        HeavenlyBody planet1 = solarSystem.get("Mars");
        System.out.println("Planet :" + planet1.getName());
        for (HeavenlyBody satellite : planet1.getSatellites()) {
            System.out.println(" \t" + satellite.getName());
        }

        HeavenlyBody plant2 = solarSystem.get("Earth");
        System.out.println("Planet :" + plant2.getName());
        for (HeavenlyBody satellite : plant2.getSatellites()) {
            System.out.println(" \t" + satellite.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

HeavenlyBody.java

```
public class HeavenlyBody {

    private String planetName;
    private double orbitalPeriod;

    private Set<HeavenlyBody> satellites;

    public HeavenlyBody(String planetName, double orbitalPeriod) {
        super();
        this.planetName = planetName;
        this.orbitalPeriod = orbitalPeriod;
        this.satellites = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Set<HeavenlyBody> getSatellites() {
        return new HashSet<>(this.satellites);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return planetName;
    }

    public double getOrbitalPeriod() {
        return orbitalPeriod;
    }

    public void addSatellite(HeavenlyBody satellite) {
        this.satellites.add(satellite);
    }
}
```

output :

```
Planet :Mars
    Phobos
    Deimos
Planet :Earth
    Moon
```

Kindly could someone explain how the object reference are allocation for object and with diagram or how sattellites added in HashMap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `solarSystem.put(heavenlyBody.getName(), heavenlyBody);` key `Mars` is put into hash map with value `heavenlyBody`. So the value **references** the object related to Mars.

In

```
HeavenlyBody satellites  = new HeavenlyBody("Phobos", 01.2);
solarSystem.put(satellites .getName(), satellites );
heavenlyBody.addSatellite(satellites );
```

first satellite Phobos is created, then it is put in hash map with key Phobos and object `satellites` as object. Then in `heavenlyBody.addSatellite(satellites );` the variable `heavenlyBody` is still a reference to Mars and it simply is added as a satellite there. The corresponding value in the hash map references the same object `heavenlyBody`. As the hash map references to this object, it "sees" the update in `heavenlyBody`.

Comment: Wow the intelegence of Hash map is awesome. Thank You so much Michael for your explanation.